# App that plays audio file from internal Storage, Android Studio (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, wav

I have attempted to create an App that plays wavfiles that have been created from another app I have made that records wavFiles.

The wav files I would like to play are stored in the following directory with  my android device.

"/data/data/com.example.androidaudiorecorder/files/"

Here is the code I have attempted so far :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button playEvent ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    playEvent= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayEvent);
    playEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playEvent( );
        }
    });
}





public static void playEvent(){
     try {
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
         player = new  MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource("/data/data/com.example.androidaudiorecorder/files/recording_DOG.wav");
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception of type : " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

 }
 }
```

Unfortunatley when I load the app and press play, nothing happens.
I am not sure if this is the correct way to use a file directory.
Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as far as I know, you can't access other apps data folder.

Comment: Would putting the code as a new activity on the original app help ?

Comment: Did you added permission?

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to give permissions in the android manifest file to access storage before reading/writing any content int the storage .

2) To read the file,

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/filename.extension");
```